# I can't fix my error

Tags: javascript

below the this text is my code
It works well when i input empty / low num / high num
however when i input string it doesn't work well

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Show error message depending on input value by using try/catch/throw</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <button id="btn1" onclick="showR()">Show the result</button>
    <p id="demo1"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showR(){
        var x;
        x= document.getElementById('input1').value;
        //x= Number(x);
        try{
            if(x=="")throw "empty";
            if(x==isNaN(x))throw "not a number";
            x= Number(x);
            if(x<5)throw "too low";
            if(x>10)throw "too high";
            document.getElementById(demo1).innerHTML=x;
        }catch(err){
            document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "input is : " + err;
        }
        document.getElementById('input1').innerHTML='hi';
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the error message is
input is : TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
what is the reason and how can i resolve this problem

Comment: `if(x==isNaN(x))` is always false ... get rid of `x==`

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) next time. It saves you a lot of time and work and reduces the need to ask typo-related questions like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(demo1).innerHTML=x;
```

this should be changed to

```
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML=x;
```

First, Learn to read the error.

Comment: "First, Learn to read the error." Great advice but maybe the OP is looking for how to find the error hence posting here.... Maybe advice to check the browser console?

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks for the **The wisdom of the answer**

Comment: [judge variable is Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)